# Change position of rows in row-fluid

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have one design specific problem, I am using bootstrap functionality of row fluid for responsiveness.Its working perfectly when I checked it on mobile device. But will want to change the position of row-fluid.For Example:

```
<div class="container">
    <div style="margin-top: 44px;"> 
        <div class="row-fluid">  
            <div class="span2">
            </div>
            <div class="span8">
                <div class="row-fluid"> 
                    <div class="span3" style="border-left: 1px solid #f5f5f5;border-right: 1px solid #f5f5f5;height: 90vh;">
                     <div id="up" style="margin-top: 50px;">    
                        <div id="A1">In same col but upper position</div>
                        <div id="A2">In same col but lower position</div>
                     </div> 
                    </div>
                    <div id="refreshDiv" class="span9" style="background: url(/sample.png) no-repeat center top;height: 90vh;border-right: 1px solid #f5f5f5;">
                        <div id="B">In same row</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="span2">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In this example inside span8 there is row-fluid for responsivness. Will want to change the order or position after responsive.Means id="A1" on top then id="B" at middle and then id="A2".I searched it on google got the answers also but the scenario of mine is different.
The current position is like:

A1
(It is on right side of both)   B

A2

After responsive I want this:

A1

B

A2

Comment: which bootstrap version are you using?

Comment: You can configure different views each being displayed on the device its intended. Eg, a different view for cellphone, another view for tablet and another for desktop. Bootstrap 2.3 provides classes which need to be added to 'div' to hide/show that part of html on the specific device. Checkout 'Responsive utility classes' on http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#responsive

Comment: I know it we can provide different design for mobile,tablet but here the case is different.Design is same its the matter of only changing the position of row-fluid.

Comment: That what i am trying to say. You cant mix or interchange the contents  of spans(here, span3 and span9 inside row-fluid). A1 & A2 are inside span3 and B is inside span9. Hence, use the provided responsive utility classes to rearrange the content based on the device. That would be easier and better to maintain. You can modify the view for any device without affecting another.